# LAMP shows index.php in var/www/html instead of project

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu-16.04.

In my `var/www/html` I have created a file called `index.php` which shows info about my PHP.

Also i have a folder called FMS which is my Codeigniter Project Folder.

When I fire

```
localhost/FMS
```

it shows the url to be :

```
localhost/FMS/secure/login
```

but displays the `index.php` page

How do I solve this?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow, please revise and tag me when you add more information.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file like /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

You need to do changes in this file, so

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

And change the document root address accordingly, it will be like */var/www/html* change it to */var/www/*

Now try to restart apache

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```